# Why is there a syntax error in my update statement in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on my Update Sql statement, but cannot find the syntax error in my code. My insert statement is working, and I am selecting their login Id from another form to compare against.

```
   conn.Open()
        Dim SqlUpdate As String = "UPDATE tblLogin SET UserPassword =@UserPassword , FirstName =@FirstName , Surname =@Surname , DateofBirth =@DateofBirth , Phonenumber =@Phonenumber , Emailaddress = @Emailaddress , Administrator = @Administrator , Height = @Height , Weight = @Weight , WHERE UserID = @UserID "
        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
        With SqlCommand
            .CommandText = SqlUpdate
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", passwordsubmitbox.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", forenamebox.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", surnamebox.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofBirth", DOBselection.Value)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber", phonenumberbox.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailaddress", emailadressbox.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Administrator", "N")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", CInt(heightbox.Text))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", CInt(weightbox.Text))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Formlogin.UsernameBox1.Text)
            .Connection = conn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()

        End With
        conn.Close()
```

Comment: there is a comma after the field weight before Where clause.remove it.it will work.

Comment: Thank you, all working now, can't believe it was just a single comma all that time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query has syntax error remove  `,` after `@Weight`

`Weight = @Weight WHERE UserI ...`